# Vue axios (and fetch) responses not passing into data property

Tags: api, vue.js, axios, fetch-api

I have a Vue (2.2.1) component that should display a membership directory by making a request to a Laravel API. The request succeeds, and the response is correct when I console.log it. Likewise, the API request succeeds in Postman and the JSON object is correctly formatted. But, the response won't pass into the variable in the Vue instance data object to which I attempt to assign it. My code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ entries }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'directory',
    data() {
      return {
        entries: []
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.getEntries()
    },
    methods: {
      getEntries: function() {
        axios.get('/api/directory')
          .then(response => {
             this.entries = response.data;
          });
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

When I load the page (after npm run dev), empty brackets representing the initial state of `entries` (an empty array) is displayed and not the raw JSON data. (I'm just testing now, not yet styling or building the table). However, if I add a `console.log(this.entries)` or `console.log(response)` or `console.log(response.data)`, the correct form of the JSON is displayed in console and there are no errors.

I have replaced the axios code with the appropriate fetch code, including the `->json()` line and get the same results. I have also used a "practice" API (JSONPlaceholder) to make sure it wasn't a problem with my API and likewise got the same results. This suggests that I'm doing something wrong in my Vue component `<script>`, but after hours of searching SO, Google, and Vue.js forum, I'm not finding anything. The closest matching link ([Vue.js cannot set data returned from external axios response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46103936/vue-js-cannot-set-data-returned-from-external-axios-response)) was of no help, unfortunately.

Comment: What do you expect by `{{ entries }}` to array of JSON? Use proper `v-for` to display the array of json properly.

Comment: @JoshuaStephen Vue will `JSON.stringify` arrays and objects inside `{{ }}`.

Comment: You have a syntax error, you didn't close the `<div>` and `<template>` tags correctly.

Comment: I just expect `{{ entries }}` to display the JSON array. The v-for bit will be coming down the line. I will have a table with `<tr v-for="entry in entries"><td>{{ entry.lname}}, {{ entry.fname}}...` down the line. I had originally written that was getting no rows, so to eliminate "moving parts", I simplified to the above code just trying to display the JSON array so as to determine whether the response was getting passed to "entries", which it isn't.

Comment: @DecadeMoon Yes, you are correct. But that's not the problem. The API response is not getting passed into `entries`.

Comment: `<pre>{{ JSON.stringify(entries, null,4 ) }}</pre>` :p

Comment: The code you have provided works. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/df4Lnuw6/417/). Something else is going on that we don't know about. Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I will do that, @DecadeMoon. I'll create a fiddle as well. I'm going to go check yours out now. Thanks.

Comment: try wrapping the `response.data` with `JSON.parse()`;

Comment: Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/watsonad/pw654zfb/8/. Any thoughts?

Comment: Declare the component *before* initializing Vue and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/dv0qjas1/ (otherwise you'll get a 'Unknown custom element: <directory>' error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make your `entries` a computed property so it will update on the call, it seems like your template is not updating a computed property may solve this.
 Try this:

```
data(){
   return {
      dataEntries: null
    }

computed: {
   entries(){
       if (dataEntries) return dataEntries
       return []
    }
```